# A question on the transition matrix. (algebraic derivation)

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, mathematics

I am trying to follow the derivation of the following identity:

$$[\epsilon -H_0+i\eta]^{-1}T = [\epsilon - H +i\eta]^{-1}U$$

where $T$ is the transition matrix and $U$ is the potential caused by the impurities.

I have also the next identity:
$$T=U+U[\epsilon-H_0+i\eta]^{-1}T$$
which I thought to use in order to prove the first identity.
In the textbook called A Quantum Approach to Condensed Matter Physics it's said that the identity:
$$[\epsilon -H_0+i\eta]^{-1}T = [\epsilon - H +i\eta]^{-1}U$$
can be seen by operating on both sides with $\epsilon-H+i\eta$ which I did but I don't see how to get to an identity which is known already before this identity.
A few more details this derivation is on pages 172-173 of the above book and also $\eta \to 0$.

I appreciate your help.

P.S
$$H=H_0+U$$
I think though it's not written explicitly in the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, express $T$ from your second equation:
$$
T = \left[I - U[\epsilon -H_0 +i\eta]^{-1}\right]^{-1} U,
$$
where $I$ is the identity operator. Second, using properties of an inverse operator, write identities:
$$
\left[I - U[\epsilon -H_0 +i\eta]^{-1}\right]^{-1} = \left[[\epsilon -H_0+i\eta -U][\epsilon-H_0+i\eta]^{-1}\right]^{-1} = [\epsilon-H_0+i\eta][\epsilon -H_0+i\eta -U]^{-1}
$$
Now we have obtained
$$
T = [\epsilon-H_0+i\eta][\epsilon -H_0+i\eta -U]^{-1}U
$$
As $H_0+U = H$, it is straightforward to obtain the needed equation from the last one.